# Which is my SQL server name for connecting to the online database by SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, database, google-compute-engine, ssms

I created a database 'dbDemo' (MS SQL Server 2012) by Plesk on Google Cloud Platform and for connecting to this database from another local machine I changed the TCP Port 1433 on my online server using [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_82d61Yhl3w) guidelines.

[image]

[image]

and I am able to login into my database by little admin. When I run SQL query I found below output

```
SELECT
 @@servername AS 'Server Name' 
,@@servicename AS 'Instance Name'
,DB_NAME() AS 'Database Name'
,HOST_NAME() AS 'Host Name'
```

Output:

```
Server Name: MY-WINDOW-INSTA\MSSQLSERVER2012
Instance Name: MSSQLSERVER2012
Database Name: dbDemo
Host Name: MY-WINDOW-INSTA
```

and My Server IP are:

> ```
> My Server IP (External): 35.240.XXX.XXX
> My Server IP (Internal): 10.XXX.X.X
> ```

Now I want to connect to my online database from a local remote machine by SQL Server Management studio...

[image]

**The above screenshot Login and Password are correct. but I am unable to find the exact value for the server name.**

I have already used the below values as a server name:

- 35.240.XXX.XXX,1433\MY-WINDOW-INSTA\MSSQLSERVER2012
- 35.240.XXX.XXX,1433\MSSQLSERVER2012
- 35.240.XXX.XXX,1433
- 35.240.XXX.XXX
- .\MSSQLSERVER2012
- MY-WINDOW-INSTA\MSSQLSERVER2012
- .\MY-WINDOW-INSTA\MSSQLSERVER2012

**Note:** I have also implement all these methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: Have you tried to connect with a different method, for example the cli for sqlserver? This because the error message can be also because the instance is not accessible due to a different reason, so this will discard or confirm that the instance is visible to your local envirornment

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

**35.240.XXX.XXX is my server name** and it is my external server IP.

Actually external IP address of my VM instance was not listening to port 1433

So for listening to port 1433 ... I run the below command to my VM machine's cmd.

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

that's it!!!